# How do I read/write a enter/newline symbol in serial communication

Tags: serial-port, ascii

I am setting up a serial connection to a very simple embedded platform. Individual bytes are meant to be sent as commands and returned as status codes. I would like to:

- when sending commands - when I push enter to send some ascii symbol to delegate the meaning, classically associated with "Enter" - continue
- when receiving codes - I want to send strings, that end up in a newline.

Is there a symbol in the [ascii](http://www.asciitable.com/) table that is customary to handle theise situations or are there  two separate or there is no such.

I am using [RealTerm](http://realterm.sourceforge.net/) under XP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depends on the os, but typically 10 is newline, and 13 is carriage return

Comment: Wow, I'm so blind. Thanks about the line feed (10). But how does carriage return imply in any way "everything OK,continue to next part of the job", which is what I use "Enter" for on the PC. For example I will hit "Enter" to post this comment.

Comment: On pretty much everything but DOS, ASCII 10 is the end of line character, so I'd just stick with that.  These ASCII characters pre-date the CRT, and were used to control Teletype Machines (There's also a bell and a backspace) 10 would advance the page, 13 would return to the beginning of the line.  More than you'd ever want to know about it [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline)  Enter is for input, typewriters had a "Return" key (return the carriage to the start of the line)

Comment: Except Mac which traditionally 13 alone, without 10.   '